# how the car dies, the link also die?

Tags: netlogo

I write a traffic simulation program. I let the car move randomly within a 10m radius. What if the car out of that circle, I command die. but faulty program is not known to be driving function? how to tell if the patient dies vehicles with vehicles that died in this, the function is not called half?
[image]

```
 if distancexy 0 0 >= 10
  [
    die
  ]
```

Comment: Seems something is going on with your plot update code. If the answer below doesn't fix your problem, could you provide more code as there may be a bug somewhere else.

Comment: re "how the car dies, the link also die?", if a turtle dies, all of the links connected to it die too. by definition, a link always connects two turtles — the link cannot exist otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask all the cars with a distance greater than 10 die.

This is called from an observer's perspective.

```
ask cars with [(distancexy 0 0) > 10] [ die]
```